# Android screen stops reading inputs

Tags: android, input, screen, loss

First off, this has never happened before on any other android device I've used (multiple devices have been tried and tested before this).
Now I have an app that I have worked on for a little over a year now, it is called AutomatedId (on the app store) and it has worked quite well for my company for quite some time.
Recently I have been given a device to add compatibility to the app (specifically for reading UHF tags) but that isn't the problem.
The problem comes whenever you open the app, the screen stops reading inputs completely, as well as buttons cease to function. I turned on developer options to see the screen inputs and as i suspected, it completely stops and does not read any of the inputs after the app is opened. Clicks don't work, buttons don't work, keyboard doesn't open, hardware buttons on the device stop working. It's a mess, does anyone know what could have caused this?

This is a S98 from here: http://www.wepoy.com/product_view_18.html

Comment: Do you have any logs for this? It might be a memory leak or any exception errors. Are you sure the phone is also working properly though?

Comment: It was a memory leak, for some reason this particular device doesn't handle a service correctly (it is suppose to return null and exit if it isn't the correct device) and causes a memory leak that stops the phone. Thanks for the advice, move your comment to the answers and I will set it as such.

Comment: Thanks for the Upvote man! appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moved my comment to the answer as you said. This may be due to memory leak. Here are some references that may help you fix them: [Fixing-Memory-Leaks-in-Android-Studio](http://www.theshiftingbit.com/Fixing-Memory-Leaks-in-Android-Studio) & use this library from square to detect memory leaks early: [leakcanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)